# How do I delete a DataRow from an EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, datarow

I want to delete a datarow from EnumerableRowCollection. Is that possible?. I am using EnumerableRowCollection instead of generic var variable to make sense my context.

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                           where results.Field("RowNo") == 1
                                           select results;

foreach(DataRow result in results)
{
    if(resultOk(result))
    delete result from results??
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you know that deleting a record from the EnumerableRowCollection won't delete it from the data store, right?

Answer (score 3):

For sure you cannot remove elements from collection you are iterating using `foreach`. That's simply forbidden and will result in runtime exception.

You might simply want to move this logic into `linq` query:

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field("RowNo") == 1 && !resultOk(myRow)
select myRow; // note that you're returning myRow, not results, like in your code
// you need to pay attention to code samples you're providing to avoid misunderstanding
```

This will return to you list with elements that you really want, with no need to remove those elements in `foreach` loop.

Comment: +1 Good answer. It's also worth pointing out that, even if you *could* remove elements inside a foreach loop, `EnumerableRowCollection<T>` doesn't provide a Remove method...

Comment: @pako, if in case i have EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> subset of results, how can delete that subset? I mean If
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> fullresults=getResults();
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> subresults=getSubResults();
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> finalResults=fullresults-subresults;
how can do this:

Comment: As @djacobson noted above, you cannot remove elements from `EnumerableRowCollection<T>`. What you can do, however, is linq-query the collection and get new results from this query to overwrite previous collection assigned to variable. Or, if you now which elements you will need to remove while running first query, include additional filters into `where` in first query.